# Concatenate two fields from different tables in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, join, concatenation

How can I concatenate two fields from two different tables in SQLite?

Say I have:

```
Id  Name                
----------  ------
1           John         
2           Doe

Id    Name                
----------  ------
1           SchoolA
2           SchoolB
```

Expected Output

```
Id   Name                
----------  ------
1           John-SchoolA         
2           Doe-SchoolB
```

NB: Both tables have the same Ids.

Updated:

**Table 1**

```
 Id        Name                
----     -------
 1         John         
 2         Doe
```

**Table 2**

```
Table1_id   Name                
---------   ------
1           SchoolA
2           SchoolB
```

NB: Both tables have the same Ids (in terms of value).

Comment: I don't really understand what do you want to do, but try to use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Do both tables have the same ids?

Comment: Then how are they related? I guess StudentId has nothing to do with SchoolId. Why do you concatenate John with SchoolA?

Comment: Yes, they do relate. Let me update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the tables on their ids and concatenate the names of the matching rows:

```
SELECT t1.Id, 
       t1.Name || '-' || t2.Name AS Name
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.Id = t1.Id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=52c7a76544a9f03667c4cf7249502c5d).

Comment: Thanks, @forpas. Does t1.Id work for SQLite 3? I got an error that no such column: t1.Name

Comment: @Bloggrammer check the demo in my answer. Did you copy the code as it is?

Comment: I got it to work, thank you. Though they both have the same Ids in terms of value, the property name isn't. I updated your last line of query with the correct property name.

Comment: @Bloggrammer in your question the columns in both tables have the same name `Name`.

Comment: Yeah. But the Id is different. Table 1 is `Id` whereas Table 2 id is `Table1_id`